# Which index option should I choose?

Tags: sql, indexing, database-design

I have a SQL table with these columns (id, A, B, C, D, E).

I usually query on (A and C) and (B and C) so I decide to have index on these 3. There are some options for this:

- Index for A,B,C separately
- Index for two pairs (A,C) and (B,C)
- Index for (A,B,C)

Which option should I choose? Database size may be an issue but let assume it's not a big deal right now.

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: pretty much any answer you get will be an educated guess. You're much better off experimenting and measuring.

Comment: @Conrad Frix. Some experimentation is always good, but there are rules to follow to start with. It's not that this is an uncommon case. Best advise is to search the answer to this question for you specific database, because that may make a difference.

Comment: @GolezTrol from the OP's statement "I usually query" I think its safe to presume that the indexs are being built to improve the performance of *existing* queries. The OP already knows what the candidate indexes are. All that's left at this point is to add the indexes and test. DB Engines have a nasty habit of not using an index when you think it should.

Comment: If you know how indexes work, you can tell that some of the candidates don't make sense. I think it's a good question, and by answering it, I saved OP the burdon of creating and testing 4 useless indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an index on the two pairs. With most indexes (although this may vary between types and databases), an index on A,B is uses as well if you query only A, but A,B is not used if you query only B. So make sure the first columns in your indexes are the columns you query for. If you query A,B and A,C, but not B or C alone, you only need the indexes on those two pairs.

Answer (score 1):

if storage/space utilization is important, than add two single column indexes, each on A and B.

if performance of these queries is more critical, then add two composite indexes, one on (A,C) and the other on (B,C).

as someone has already commented, these suggestions are educated guesses. it is a good idea to experiment with a variety of options to find the optimal indexing strategy.